# Import saved KQL queries from ARM template to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I've been setting up [monitoring Azure Databricks in an Azure Log Analytics Workspace](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring) and managed to get logs going to an existing log analytics workspace I have.

However, I failed to notice that an [ARM template](https://github.com/mspnp/spark-monitoring/blob/master/perftools/deployment/loganalytics/logAnalyticsDeploy.json) was supplied for setting up a new workspace that contains a bunch of useful KQL saved queries.

**I would like those saved queries in the log analytics instance I've started out with already, is there a way I can import them?**

I've noticed there is an API for [creating or updating saved queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/savedsearches/createorupdate), however, this seems to only create / update individual queries and I would prefer to import all the queries mentioned in the above link in one go. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such feature for importing them.

You should create these saved queries by yourself, by using `azure portal`, or [Saved Searches - Create Or Update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/savedsearches/createorupdate), or `azure cli commands`: [az monitor log-analytics workspace saved-search create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/workspace/saved-search?view=azure-cli-latest#az_monitor_log_analytics_workspace_saved_search_create) etc.

Comment: This is frustrating, but understandable. Thanks for answering